# Tkinter Notebook only showing a few rows of output

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make a Tkinter notebook that shows a data table. Currently, it shows only the top part of the data table I built. I've tried adjusting the height of tab frames and the overall notebook but nothing changes the output size.

```
class LEMSDataCruncher_L2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root): #Set window
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)

        #vertical scrollbar
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")

        # horizontal scrollbar
        self.hsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal", command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self.hsb.set)
        self.hsb.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.create_window((8, 8), window=self.frame, anchor="nw",
                                  tags="self.frame")

        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)

        # File Path Entry
        tk.Label(self.frame, text="Select Folder:").grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.folder_path_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.folder_path = tk.Entry(self.frame, textvariable=self.folder_path_var, width=150)
        self.folder_path.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # Initialize energy_files as an instance variable
        self.energy_files = []

        # create a button to browse folders on computer
        browse_button = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Browse", command=self.on_browse)
        browse_button.grid(row=0, column=1)

        # Create a notebook to hold tabs
        #self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self.canvas)
        #self.notebook.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        # OK button
        ok_button = tk.Button(self.frame, text="OK", command=self.on_okay)
        ok_button.anchor()
        ok_button.grid(row=3, column=0)

        # Bind the MouseWheel event to the onCanvasMouseWheel function
        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self.onCanvasMouseWheel)

        self.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=True)

    def onCanvasMouseWheel(self, event):
        # Adjust the view of the canvas based on the mouse wheel movement
        if event.delta > 0:
            self.canvas.yview_scroll(-1, "units")
        elif event.delta < 0:
            self.canvas.yview_scroll(1, "units")

    def on_okay(self):  # When okay button is pressed
        error = []
        # Create a notebook to hold tabs
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(height=30000)
        self.notebook.grid(row=0, column=0)
        for folder in self.energy_files:
            try:
                output_path = folder.replace('EnergyInputs.csv', 'EnergyOutputs.csv')
                log_path = folder.replace('EnergyInputs.csv', 'log.txt')
                [trail, units, data, logs] = LEMS_EnergyCalcs(folder, output_path, log_path)

                # Create a new frame for each tab
                tab_frame = tk.Frame(self.notebook, height=300000)
                tab_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

                # Set up the frame as you did for the original frame
                self.frame = tk.Frame(tab_frame, background="#ffffff")
                self.frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

                # round to 3 decimals
                round_data = {}
                for name in data:
                    try:
                        rounded = round(data[name].n, 3)
                    except:
                        rounded = data[name]
                    round_data[name] = rounded

                data = round_data

                # Output table
                self.create_output_table(data, units, logs, num_columns=150,
                                         num_rows=300,
                                         folder_path=folder)  # Adjust num_columns and num_rows as needed

                self.frame.configure(height=300*3000)
                # Add the tab to the notebook with the folder name as the tab label
                self.notebook.add(tab_frame, text=os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(folder)))

            except PermissionError:
                error.append(folder)

        if error:
            message = f"One or more files are open in another program. Close them and try again."
            # Error
            messagebox.showerror("Error", message)

        # Set the notebook to recenter the view to top-left when a tab is selected
        self.notebook.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda event: self.canvas.yview_moveto(0))

    def create_output_table(self, data, units, logs, num_columns, num_rows, folder_path):
        # Destroy any existing widgets in the frame
        for widget in self.frame.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()

        # Create a new OutputTable instance and pack it into the frame
        output_table = OutputTable(self.frame, data, units, logs, num_columns, num_rows, folder_path)
        #output_table.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        output_table.grid(row=0, column=0)
class OutputTable(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, data, units, logs, num_columns, num_rows, folder_path):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)

        # Exit button
        exit_button = tk.Button(self, text="EXIT", command=root.quit, bg="red", fg="white")
        exit_button.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=(350, 5), pady=5, sticky="e")

        self.find_entry = tk.Entry(self, width=100)
        self.find_entry.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=0, pady=0, columnspan=3)

        find_button = tk.Button(self, text="Find", command=self.find_text)
        find_button.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=0, pady=0)
        self.text_widget.tag_configure("bold", font=("Helvetica", 12, "bold"))

        header = "{:<110}|".format("ALL ENERGY OUTPUTS")
        self.text_widget.insert(tk.END, header + "\n" + "_" * 63 + "\n", "bold")
        header = "{:<64} | {:<31} | {:<18} |".format("Variable", "Value", "Units")
        self.text_widget.insert(tk.END, header + "\n" + "_" * 63 + "\n", "bold")

        self.cut_table = tk.Text(self, wrap="none", height=num_rows, width=72)
        # Configure a tag for bold text
        self.cut_table.tag_configure("bold", font=("Helvetica", 12, "bold"))

        self.cut_table.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=0, pady=0, columnspan=3)
        cut_header = "{:<113}|".format("WEIGHTED METRICS")
        self.cut_table.insert(tk.END, cut_header + "\n" + "_" * 63 + "\n", "bold")
        cut_header = "{:<64} | {:<31} | {:<18} |".format("Variable", "Value", "Units")
        self.cut_table.insert(tk.END, cut_header + "\n" + "_" * 63 + "\n", "bold")
        for key, value in data.items():
            unit = units.get(key, "")
            try:
                val = value.n
            except:
                val = value

            if not val:
                val = " "
            if not unit:
                unit = " "
            if key.endswith('weighted'):
                row = "{:<35} | {:<17} | {:<10} |".format(key, val, unit)
                self.cut_table.insert(tk.END, row + "\n")
                self.cut_table.insert(tk.END, "_" * 70 + "\n")
```

image of the cut off data table:

[image: image of the cut off data table]

I've tried both pack with `fill="both"` and `expand=True` and `grid`. I've tried changing the notebook and frame size.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] as currently `OutputTable` is undefined.

Comment: @acw1668 I've updated the code to include more of it

Comment: From the image, the two `Text` boxes have height of *one line*, so only one line of text can be shown.  The posted code is still incomplete as I cannot find any code of setting the height of the text boxes to one.